# Custom View. Get location of a point in a rotated view, on the parent

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

The scenario is that I have a View with custom drawings inside the white background FrameLayout. Without rotation it is just a flat circle. But as I have set the view's rotationX (3D x axis) using

```
View.setRotationX(50f);
```

It looks like this:

[image]

If flat circle view, I can easily get the location of the **black circle with a line of the view**, since it is the same size as the frame layout. Meaning if it is on X(32),Y(100), its location on the frame layout is X(32), Y(100). But how do I get its correct relative location X and Y, on the FrameLayout if the view is rotated and the FrameLayout is not?

What I can only provide is the XY location of the point on the view when it wasn't still rotated.

Comment: || Disclaimer: Just a thought || Maybe run an invisible view of the above shown layout but all without any angels and tilts and get your co-ords off of that? Then just use your above view as a view to show to the user but no actual code is gathered from it. Only code that then transmits to the hidden view that then you do your calculations off of?

Comment: I see I might have gotten your question wrong another time, but I feel this time we're closer. if you look at the drawing I posted, you have B and you want to find A?

Comment: @lelloman lemme take a while understanding it I still am working on it

Comment: yea, my answer now works like this, you click on the frame layout, and you have the coordinates of the click. then it will give you the equivalent coordinate of the custom view as if it wasn't rotated

Answer (score 1):

apparently I was wrong, calculating only for rotationX is not easier because of the perspective projection. so, this is how you can do it, yStar will be 1 for the top of the View and -1 for the bottom, for the x coordinate you can use the same as the touch since you're rotating on x axis it won't change

```
final float rotationDegrees = 45 ;
final double rotationRadians = Math.toRadians(rotationDegrees);
final double ninetyDegrees = Math.toRadians(90);
customView.setRotationX(rotationDegrees);

frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            float cy = frameLayout.getHeight() / 2;

            float yt = (event.getY() - cy) / -cy;

            double ms = Math.tan(ninetyDegrees + rotationRadians);
            double targetX = (yt-ms) / ms;
            double targetY = (Math.pow(yt, 2) - yt*ms) / ms;

            double yStar = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(targetX- -1, 2) + Math.pow(targetY- 0, 2));

            if(targetY>0) yStar *= -1;

            Log.d("MainActivity", String.valueOf(yStar));

        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

explanation:

imagine that the segment on the right that goes from (1;1) to (1;-1) is your FrameLayout, viewed from the side. the line on the left that goes from (-1;1) to (-1;-1) is your custom view, not rotated.
[image]
A is the point on which you're touching the FrameLayout. R is the projection of the touch, it passes through the origin, which is the focal point. S is the line on which your rotated view lays on. B is the point on the rotated view where the touch on the FrameLayout is projected. the y coordinate (yStar) of the touch on the rotated view is the distance between B and F (F is the center of the custom view)

once you have the picture of all the lines and point here's how you can compute yStar:

yt = y coordinate of the touch on FrameLayout scaled between -1 and 1
A = (1;yt)
R = (x-1)/-1 = (y-yt) / -yt -> line passing through A and origin
R = y = -yt((x-1) / -1) + yt
R = y = -yt * (-x+1) + yt
R = y = yt * x
S = y = ms * x + ms -> line with slope ms passing through F (-1;0)
ms = tan(90+rotationAngle)

B will be the intersetction between R and S. if they have the same slope (ms = yt) there will be no intersection.
so

yt * x = ms * x +ms
yt * x - ms * x = ms
x * (yt - ms) = ms
x = (yt - ms) / ms -> the x coordinate of B

y = yt * ((yt - ms) / ms)
y = (yt^2 - yt * ms) / ms -> the y coordinate of B

now compute distance from F and multiply by -1 if y is below F.

Comment: Hi I understood your answer however that is not the case. The Circle view there is rotated 50 degrees in X axis, meaning it's like a coin flipped a little. without the rotation, it is just a flat circle with the line on the left side as a straight line. the dot on the line's coordinate is easy to locate on framelayout because they will be totally the same. However, if the view is rotated on xaxis 50degrees, it's location on the framelayout will totally be different. That's what I am trying to get.

Comment: @Sheychan anyway I think that the problem is even easier only for the x, I'm going to eat something and then update the answer